Cremating the ashes of the deceased or double cremation
Is there a ritual in Hinduism where a person who was deceased faraway from the family but was cremated by the locals. The ashes transported to the family and the family again cremates the ashes to fulfil their ritualistic obligations? Is there such a ritual that takes place this way in the modern day?
